# How do I use SQL kind join on Case Condition success query execution in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, join, aggregation-framework, conditional-statements, lookup

I have a use case where I need to join two collections in MongoDB but the join must happen only if one of the two conditions are met.
The SQL equivalent query is given below. How can I translate this in MongoDB?

```
SELECT *
FROM MainTble i
Left JOIN SecondTable p
ON CASE
WHEN i.myPropert="SMS" and i.phoneNumber = p.phoneNumber THEN 1
WHEN i.myProperty="Email" and i.email = p.email THEN 1
ELSE 0
END = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) to achieve a similar behaviour. In the sub-pipeline, use `$addFields` to create a helper field then `$match` on the helper field to filter the `$lookup` / join result.

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pYbWwSOd6Ll) for your reference.